# Using CURL to handle all the cookie stuff like a browser?

Tags: http, web-crawler, session-cookies

Recently I am using `curl` to crawl the recommended question list from [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com) based on my signedin account.

Currently, in order to register my account info in the HTTP request, I copy and paste the headers+cookies(displayed by my browser) into a file, wrote a script in which `curl` is used to crawl the data.

However, as I noticed, some keys in the `Cookie` field, like the `__utma` and `__utmb`, sent by the browser regularly changes, thus I have to update my cookie value in the script accordingly, otherwise, I will not be able to get the result based on my account information.

This necessary update on my side is quite cumbersome indeed.

My confusion are:
1, why is the cookie field(sent by the browser) regularly changing? What is the reason  behind that?
2, Is there anyway to make CURL behave like the browser so that it can adapt the cookie in the same way as the browser?

Answer (score 0):

1 - cookies are "set" by the server and the client only sends them back if they match the same server+path etc like when they were set. Servers can very well set the cookie over and over to new values and then the browser (or curl) of course need to send back the correct contents.

2 - as long as the cookies are set with HTTP there is (see [http-cookies](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html) for an overview), but if the cookies are set by for example javascript then curl won't mimic the browser since curl doesn't run any such programs while the browsers do.